# What is the most professional way of dealing with too many messages on LinkedIn?

Tags: recruitment, linkedin

I am now receiving more messages and invitations on LinkedIn than I can handle. These messages almost always contain invitation the the phone/skype/onsite interview.

I have no interests right now in changing jobs (I just started few weeks ago in the new workplace) but at the same time I don't want to burn any bridges with potential future employers and recruiters. However I don't want to spend my time every single day on LinkedIn replying to the messages or accepting invitations from the unknown people.

I did post 3 months ago this message on my LinkedIn profile (which is my only post out there):

> Hello all,
>   I don't like to ignore any human being but I don't have time to reply
>   to every message here. So to make it clear:
>
> I am not looking for a new job since I've already signed with another
>   company. So at least for the next year I am good, thanks.
>
> Should I be looking for a new job I will use the switch on LinkedIn
>   "tell recruiters that you are open".
>
> Thanks.

but it seems like people don't even bother to read it before writing to me.

How do I handle it this situation? Is ignoring all notifications from LinkedIn for the next two years or so the only way to go?

edit: the field is software engineering and I am located currently in Scandinavia.

Comment: If you are sure you have "not looking for job" you can just ignore those messages. If recruiters send you such message they just blindly trying to get leads.

Answer (score 2):

1. Linkedin has a way for you to mark your profile as not looking for a job. If you click on Jobs, one of the questions that will pop up on the screen is asking where you are in your job search. You can select the "Not open to job offers" option. This won't stop the messages, but it's more likely to be seen by recruiters than a post saying you don't want offers.
2. Recruiters typically are blasting out form emails to people that are matching search criteria. In other words, they won't really notice if you never reply. Additionally, you do not owe a professional courtesy of replying to every unsolicited contact you receive. You do not need to worry about not responding. If that's too unpalatable, you can respond with a one line form message to the effect of:

> Thank you for your interest, but I'm not open to looking at the job market right now.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here. Sadly Linkedin has no specific option yet to block recruiters aside from simply not checking the box that says you're looking for a job but there's options. You're correct that most recruiters don't even bother to read, they just message anyone. Copy/paste and go. You shouldn't feel too bad about ignoring these people as they have no personal intentions. They just need to fill a position and want their bonus.

1. Go to Settings & Privacy > Select Communications > Navigate to the Messages from members settings. While you can’t block all recruiters you can customize who is able to reach out as well as your auto-response.
2. Just ignore the messages. Delete them if you want to. No bridges burned, just no response for them. They're probably not sitting and waiting for your reply personally.
3. The idea of posting a message to your wall is good, but it's not to the point enough in my opinion. The first sentence should already say 'I am not currently open for any job offers.' Short, simple and polite.

Comment: +1 to undo negative "moderation" done on opinion and not merit. It is a perfectly valid stance.

Answer (score 0):

A large percentage of those messages are automated nowadays. Feel free to ignore them.

As for interviews/requests to talk, if you are not that interested, just say your are not considering moving right now, for the ones that might remotely interest you, ask for the job description/the job advert before even trying to talk with them.

I have had for long in my wall something similar to "Contacts without job specifications/adverts are not welcomed."

PS. In the past I just tried to make any interview people asked me, and some weeks were stressful. It is not worth it. On the other side, nowadays I prefer to give priority to my time with family and my work.